# TwitterKit for Swift

Tags: swift, twitter, twitterkit

How to import twitterkit into swift? I have tried :

> "#import < TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h>"

But that doesn't allow function calls.

Comment: Have you tried just `import TwitterKit`?

Comment: The `#import` directive is for Objective-C. Why would you use it in Swift?

Comment: I have that line : import TwitterKit

Compiler still says Use of" Unresolved identifier "-->Did you mean TWRTweetView'

The install page talks about a bridging header, but no pop-up in xcode shows up when importing TwitterKit

Answer (score -1):

TwitterKit can be imported with

`import TwitterKit`

I've tested this

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```